# Parsing multi-line variables using grep

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep, tr

I am trying to figure out why this does not work and of course how to address it, I have a long list of dates in a variable and would like to count the number of occurrences using grep, it seems like splitting a variable over new lines does not work as expected? Example,

```
$ list="2015-a 2015-b 2016-a" ; count=`echo $list | tr " " \\n | grep 2015 | wc -l` ; echo $count
1


$ list="2015-a,2015-b,2016-a" ; count=`echo $list | tr , \\n | grep 2015 | wc -l` ; echo $count
1


$ list="2015-a,2015-b,2016-a" ; count=`echo $list | sed s/,/\\n/g | grep 2015 | wc -l` ; echo $count
1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `echo "2015-a 2015-b 2016-a" |grep -o "2015" | wc -l`

Comment: It works if you say `tr " " "\n"`.

Comment: By the way, for those checking this question: there is a synonym request to merge `tr` into `html-table`. Vote it down! http://stackoverflow.com/tags/html-table/synonyms More info in [Can we undo suggestion to make [tr] be a synonym of [html-table]?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311194/1983854)

Comment: Just use `grep -o 2015` and you get multiple occurrences in the same line

Comment: Thanks a ton for introducing me to grep -o !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way backticks interpret `\\`:

> Backslashes () inside backticks are handled in a non-obvious manner:
>
> ```
>   $ echo "`echo \\a`" "$(echo \\a)"
>   a \a
>   $ echo "`echo \\\\a`" "$(echo \\\\a)"
>   \a \\a
>   # Note that this is true for *single quotes* too!
>   $ foo=`echo '\\'`; bar=$(echo '\\'); echo "foo is $foo, bar is $bar" 
>   foo is \, bar is \\
> ```

So instead of saying:

```
$ echo "`echo $list | tr " " \\n`"
2015-an2015-bn2016-a
```

You have to say:

```
$ echo "`echo $list | tr " " \\\\n`"
2015-a
2015-b
2016-a
```

Even though it is best to use `$()` because backticks are deprecated:

```
$ echo "$(echo $list | tr " " '\n')"
2015-a
2015-b
2016-a
```

If you still want to use backticks, the cleanest solution is to use `" "` as a wrapper instead of escaping with such a `\\\\`:

```
$  echo "`echo $list | tr " " "\n"`"
2015-a
2015-b
2016-a
```

All of this can be read in [Why is $(...) preferred over `...` (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

---

All in all, if you just want to count how many words contain `2015` you may consider using `grep -o` as suggested in the comments or maybe something more robust like this `awk`:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~2015) count++; print count}'
```

See some examples:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~2015) s++; print s}' <<< "2015-a 2015-b 2016-a"               2
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~2015) s++; print s}' <<< "2015-a 2015-b 2016-a 20152015-c"
3
```